# Testing in Redux - what is now the best way?

Tags: redux

I've been doing a lot of reading up on testing in Redux and am seeing two different methods of testing. Just wondering what is everyone now suggesting on the best or better method of testing is. From what I can see, the more common way is to test your actions, reducers, selectors like in the Redux docs - https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests/

This tests however looks more like they are testing the implementational details to me rather than behavioural. Therefore after looking around I came across Testing Library which writes tests in a more behavioural style, however seems less common - https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux

Would be great to hear peoples feedback on what method you're now using/recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Context: I work on a React Native app that has a shared-package with a web app. In shared-package, I have the store (with 90%+ coverage). So here is my opinion.

---

**Testing Redux:**

*Pros:*

- Testing actions, reducers, selectors are way easier then react components as it's just unit testing.

*Cons:*

- Actions, reducers, selectors have the same shape so it's a lot of boilerplate.
- testing action creators is the worst as all tests look like.

```js
it('Should create an action of SET SELECTED SUCCESS', () => {
    const expectedAction = {
      type: ModuleA_ActionEnum.SET_SELECTED_SUCCESS,
      payload: fakeSuccess,
    };
    expect(moduleA_Actions.setSelectedSuccess(fakeSuccess)).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
```

*Tips:*

- Use [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions), for static testing of actions (and ignore coverage for actions).
- If you do a lot of requests with middleware like redux-saga use [redux-saga-requests](https://github.com/klis87/redux-saga-requests) (or other tools, or create your own) that creates actions and reducers in a generic form and is tested only once.
- Test only reducers and selectors.

**Testing React components:**

*Pros:*

- Not so much boilerplate, as components behavior differs.
- More interesting.

*Cons:*

- Hard to set up (create wrappers, mock store, ThemeProvider ...), even harder for React Native.
- Hard to test some components.

**Conclusion:**

I would test both Redux and React components. Use tools to reduce boilerplate and reduce test amount.

For the `redux` folder I will try to reach 90%+ coverage (ignore files if needed).

For React components will try to test as much as I can, but if it takes to much time add `// @todo add test for this component` and work on it in free time between features (like waiting for QA).